# Linking to non-default libraries when building boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have a dependency issue with dynamic linked libs due to my boost library using one version of a lib and my Qt using another. (1.52 and 1.54).

To decrease the number of dependencies I would like to build/link boost against the 1.54 version.

I can't get the b2 build to change paths though, it uses the lib from /usr/lib and I can't figure out how to change that (ldd always shows .52). I've tried the 'link' and 'search' Properties in b2, but the output seems unchanged. Does anyone know how to specify which libraries to link?

Comment: What do you mean by the path here? Output path for boost libraries or something else?

Comment: more like how to choose which version of a library that boost libs should depend on. when i do ldd on libboost_regex.so.1.54.0 for example it looks for the older lib (52) but I want it to use the newer (54) that is located in my project directory.